# Disable Gnome 3 notifications/pop-ups/integrated notifications

Tags: linux, desktop, fedora, gnome-3

I would like to disable the Gnome 3 notifications/pop-ups/integrated notifications (if that's even the right term for them).  For example, they're the notifications that appear when your receive an IM via Empathy, or when Rhythmbox begins playing a new track.

I have downloaded the Gnome 3 Tweak Tool, but cannot find a solution in there.  I have searched Google, the Gnome website, and the local help (via F1) but cannot find a way to turn these off.  I would welcome either a solution here or a link to instructions.

I have also looked through all the hidden files in my home directory, and in /usr/share directories, and run quite a few find commands grepping (case-insensitive) for "Notification" and all sorts of substrings thereof.

I tried this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvNm3BnymAE but that did not stop the notifications from occurring.

Info:

Fedora 15 2.6.40.6-0.fc15.i686
GDM 3.0.4

Comment: In my case, this answer from superuser help me: https://superuser.com/a/908310

Answer (score 16):

If you have Gnome 3.2, you simply click on your user menu at the top-right and flip the Notifications switch.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in 3.0, if you set your status to Busy, the notifications will be suppressed.

Comment: With other versions, you might need to: click on top right corner of screen> settings> notifications> flip the switch

Answer (score 8):

On Gnome 3.28.4: At top-right corner of screen: Settings > Notifications > Flip the switch:

[image: screenshot]

From CLI:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false
```

Answer (score 3):

I was frustrated about this too.

Install dconf-editor, run it, and go to

org.gnome.empathy.notifications

and disable the first three options (signin, signout, away).

Comment: "empathy" - the irony

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

> Take a look in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-fallback.session.  Near the end of the file, you should see "RequiredProviders=windowmanager;notifications;".  Just delete "notifications;" from that line.

[source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=931875#p931875)

Comment: but then, what if you WANT notifications later on? kind of a pain :-/

Comment: it's all css and javascript.  just comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/components/autrunManager.js and comment out the following line:

```
Main.messageTray.add(this);
```

For me it was on line 546, but who knows how it scoots around in other versions of gnome.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like I maybe did this in the past and it worked, yet now some update brought back a notification I don't want... And I went to do this, and... well, trying `cd /usr/share/gnome-shell; ls -ld js` gets me: `ls: cannot access 'js': No such file or directory`.  Anyone know if this got moved somewhere else?  I've done a bit of digging, but not yet found it.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

Another location using the dconf editor is under org.gnome.desktop.notifications.  There is a large string there that has all the applications that will receive the gnome notification. If the app has its own notifications you can enable them in the app and disable the system notification in org.gnome.desktop.notifications